# Access google cloud secret inside cloud build yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager, cloudbuild.yaml

I am trying to get the secrets from google secret manager. As per documentation to access the secret, the entrypoint should be bash, but I've different entrypoint. Trying to figure out how I can get the secret in my step 'Create dataflow template'. Seems environment variable value is not accessible outside step.

```
steps:
  - id: 'Pull dataflow-python3 docker image & load secrets'    
    name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        git rev-parse --short HEAD > COMMIT_ID
        commitId=$(cat COMMIT_ID)
        echo "Project Id is $PROJECT_ID"
        echo "Commit SHA is $COMMIT_SHA"
        echo "Commit Id is ${commitId}"
        echo "Secret key 'TEST' has value '$$TEST'"
    secretEnv: ['TEST']

  - id: "Activate virtual environment venv"
    name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args: [ '-c', 'source /venv/bin/activate' ]
    waitFor: ['-']

  - id: "Create dataflow template"
    name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3:latest'
    entrypoint: 'python'
    args: 
    - -m
    - main
    - --job_name=test-df
    - --project=$PROJECT_ID
    - --region=us-east1
    - --template_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/templates/send-alert-template
    - --staging_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/staging/
    - --temp_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/temp/
    - --runner=DataflowRunner
    - --setup_file='./setup.py'
    - --autoscaling_algorithm=NONE
    - --DUMMY=$$TEST
    secretEnv: ['TEST']
    waitFor: [
      'Pull dataflow-python3 docker image & load secrets',
      'Activate virtual environment venv'
      ]

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/my-project/secrets/TEST/versions/latest
    env: 'TEST'
```

Value passed in Dataflow Pipeline

[image]

Secret value:

[image]

Build Log 1:
[image]

Build Log 2:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @sethvargo I am not getting error, the value passed to pipe line is coming as '$TEST'. Added the screen shot

Comment: What value do you expect? Did you check the value stored in SecretManager? (Ok, it's a stupid question, but just double check!)

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere added screenshot

Comment: I am not sure it has any relation with substitution variable as $$TEST is converted to $TEST. As per doc env variables are accessed by $$ followed by env variable name https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Comment: Can you try another thing? put in double quote your arg value like this `- "--DUMMY=$$TEST"`.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No luck

Comment: `$$` is "escaping" the first dollar

Comment: @sethvargo Right. $$ within step 0 is evaluated correctly, but at step 2 it's escaping. I am wondering env variables is not shared between steps in yaml. Doc says it can be. https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config

```secretEnv: A list of global environment variables, encrypted using a Cloud Key Management Service crypto key, that will be available to all build steps in this build. These values must be specified in the build's Secret.```

Comment: @sethvargo, it's the same behavior as the environment variable. Not very intuitive user experience. I'm going to email David

Answer (score 1):

I tested in different configuration and the behavior is "consistent" with [the env parameter](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config#env) in Cloud Build. In fact you can't use `env` or `secretEnv` like a substitution variables.

The `env` and `secretEnv` are only available in the execution context of the command, not in the configuration of the command.

That means:

- if you run an app or a script which use environment variables, the `env` and `secretEnv` work.
- if you use the `env` or `secretEnv` in the args of a step, it doens't work.

---

But it's subtil

Here is the context of the the execution of BASH command -> Work

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - -c
      - echo $$TEST
    secretEnv: ['TEST']
```

Here in argument of the step echo -> Don't work

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: "echo"
    args:
      - $$TEST
    secretEnv: ['TEST']
```

---

So to fix your problem, do this

```
  - id: "Create dataflow template"
    name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: 
    - -c
    - python main \
     --job_name=test-df \
     --project=$PROJECT_ID \
     --region=us-east1 \
     --template_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/templates/send-alert-template \
     --staging_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/staging/ \
     --temp_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/temp/ \
     --runner=DataflowRunner \
     --setup_file='./setup.py' \
     --autoscaling_algorithm=NONE \
     --DUMMY=$$TEST
    secretEnv: ['TEST']
    waitFor: [
      'Pull dataflow-python3 docker image & load secrets',
      'Activate virtual environment venv'
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code offered by @guillaume blaquiere will work, but the root cause of the issue is the `entrypoint`, as mentioned in [Configuring builds to access the secret from Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#configuring_builds_to_access_the_secret_from):

> In the build step where you want to specify the secret:
>
> - **Add an entrypoint field pointing to bash** to use the bash tool in the build step. **This is required to refer to the environment variable for the secret.**
> - Add a secretEnv field specifying the environment variable.
> - **In the args field, add a -c flag as the first argument**. **Any string you pass after -c is treated as a command**. For more information on running bash commands with -c, see the bash documentation.
> - When specifying the secret in the args field, specify it using the environment variable prefixed with $$.

In your example you use:

```
 entrypoint: 'python'
args: 
    - -m
```

The `entrypoint` is not `bash` and the first arg is not set the flag `-c`.

This also happens with the example of Guillaume:

```
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: "echo"
    args:
      - $$TEST
    secretEnv: ['TEST']
```

The entrypoint is not `bash`, but in his first example it is.

On the other hand, in the solution offered, the entry point is `bash` and the first arg is the flag `-c`, so this will work:

```
- id: "Create dataflow template"
    name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: 
    - -c
    - python main \
     --job_name=test-df \
     --project=$PROJECT_ID \
     --region=us-east1 \
     --template_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/templates/send-alert-template \
     --staging_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/staging/ \
     --temp_location=gs://my-project-dataflow-templates/test-alerts-template/temp/ \
     --runner=DataflowRunner \
     --setup_file='./setup.py' \
     --autoscaling_algorithm=NONE \
     --DUMMY=$$TEST
    secretEnv: ['TEST']
    waitFor: [
      'Pull dataflow-python3 docker image & load secrets',
      'Activate virtual environment venv'
      ]
```

The solution is accurate but the reason is the `entrypoint` and the first flag `-c`